# Jenkins Slave (service) , cannot detect protractor

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor

We are using slave as service and we r trying to run protractor with simple batch file after calling to npm install , but from some reason protractor was not detected, do u know what could be the reason/problem?

if i use web option (slave) for running job - everything went fine,

BTW - I try to set the service with user that allowed to run the test, and also set node in PATH, but nothing help

Appreciate your comments,
Thanks
Eyal

Comment: Please show all cmds in the batch file

Comment: from the root of the work space we are running the following commands: 
npm install,
npm install -g protractor,
webdriver-manager update

Answer (score 0):

because you install protractor as a global package, So you should use `webdriver-manager` from global package install folder. The current folder where you execute `npm install -g protractor` has no `webdriver-manager` this cmd/binary. So jenkins report can't find `webdriver-manager` in current folder or `PATH`.

For best practice, you should add `protractor` as your nodejs project's dependency through `npm install -S protractor` before you write script, after do that, you will found 'protractor' will be add into `package.json`.

When others who get your source code, he only need to execute `npm install` under folder where `package.json` insides to get all dependencies installed.

After `npm install` done, the `webdriver-manager` will be found `<package.json file inside folder>\node_modules\.bin\webriver-manager`

So your cmd should write down as following:

```
pwd
ls -l "${WORKSPACE}"
cd /d <package.json file inside folder>
npm install

node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update
node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js
```

Comment: Thank You yong, we are using package.json and protractor is define their, but i still got protractor is not recognized as internal command... , so i installed it as global and define it on PATH, so now I'm fine but now the webdriver-manager throw error : Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

Comment: I have updated webdriver-manager in 2 places under root project and under node_modules\bin

Comment: Please add `ls -l "${WORKSPACE}"` at the first line in your Jenkins cmd/shell plugin window.  Run your job and put the output of  `ls -l "${WORKSPACE}"` in your question.  I need to know the folder structure under your jenkins job workspace.  I still suspect you not `cd` correct folder before execute `npm install`. Forgot one thing, you job execute windows or linux?

Comment: Thanks Yong, we use windows, so i see the $WORKSPACE$ of Jenkins and i see the correct path, anyway i succeeded to solve the problem by using global protractor and webdriver-manager , I'm not sure its the best practice but it is working , from some reason when I used without global and package.json was fine, the protractor was not recognized... Thanks for your comments Eyal

Comment: use global protractor is not a good practice, image everyone use global protractor,  you can control the version confliction when install protractor globally.

Comment: Agree with you, my workaround to that problem is to use specific protractor version as global but other package will still be based on package.json

Comment: And its looks as Jenkins issues working with slave as service